Analog Devices module
I'm looking to identify an Analog Devices module. It's 1.125" by 1.125" by 0.375"And has their Logo, the name Analog Devices, and 52K. It's a DIP more-or-less and has 2 rows of 4 pines each.

Can you please share an image?

How old is the device?
Analog Devices made a "Low Noise, Low Drift Precision FET Amplifier MODEL 52" (both J and K) in the early 1980s.  This sounds like that. Check it out here on page a page labeled: "OPERATIONAL AMPLIFIERS VOL. II,4-21".  I expect to find things like that when going through stuff I inherited from my (BSEE 1942) father but not from anything more recent. When looking up stuff like that in the catalog it always says "Do not use for new designs."  I can see that, if they made it in 1982, it is "unlikely" you are going to find a ready supply these days.
